# WCF JSON service hosted in MVC project trying to resolve to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, wcf

I have the following WCF service hosted in an MVC project:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRegistrationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    RegisterUserResponse RegisterUser(string callback, string email, string forename, string surname);
}


[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class RegistrationService : IegistrationService
{
    public RegisterUserResponse RegisterUser(string callback, string email, string forename, string surname)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and in the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="WcfServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfEndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
 </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings> <services>
  <service name="Peninsula.Online.Application.Implementations.FreemiumRegistrationService" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" name="FreemiumRegistrationService" contract="Peninsula.Online.Application.Contracts.IFreemiumRegistrationService" address="" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" behaviorConfiguration="WcfEndpointBehavior">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

This is called from a raw html page with JQuery Ajax calling 'TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc/RegisterUser'. It all works fine on my local machine, but when I try to access the code on the UAT server I get the error:

**The IControllerFactory 'Project.Name.Changed.StructureMapControllerActivator' did not return a controller for the name 'RegistrationService.svc'.**

I can call 'TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc' and 'TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc?wdsl' and get the expected results, but as soon as I call 'TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc/RegisterUser it no longer treats it as a WCF service but as an MVC controller and tries ro resolve it as such. I assume I have a different setting in IIS or something not installed on the UAT server but cannot find what it is.

**Edit: as requested, here is the Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: "TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc/RegisterUser", 
    data: data,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response) {
        //...
    }
});
```

but really this shouldn't matter because just calling TheProjectUrl/RegistrationService.svc/RegisterUser doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it have something with the mvc routes, have you created a new route for your service?

Comment: also, post your ajax call

Comment: No but I shouldn't need to - it should be using MVC, and this expected behaiour works on my local machine, it is only on UAT that it tries to resolve it as MVC.

Comment: @RômuloSpier see edit for ajax call, but as I say, this isn't the issue.

Comment: try setting your ajax contenttype to `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: The ajax call is not the problem, it all works locally, the UAT server is resolving the request differently to how my local server is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

try this in routes definition

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
```